# How can I explain about someone who is beside without saying their name for example "he likes to eat fruits"

Tags: politeness, phrase-requests, pronouns

Is it possible for me to use あの人は　その人は　この人は to address somebody (instead of using their name) who is beside me because i'm doing a presentation and i'm required to describe somebody but that person will also be there to describe himself. If it is possible which one is the most suitable? Or is there any other way to adress them

Comment: What is the relation between you, that other person, and the audience?

Comment: I would probably use 彼。（かれ）which means "he".

Comment: Female counterpart of かれ is 彼女｛かのじょ｝.  Gender neutral would probably be something like この人.

Answer (score 1):

この人 etc are OK, but could sound a little too casual and intimate for to some extent formal situations. Basically, 彼 or 彼女 are safer in those cases.